# c++ customization point object pattern. Argument and customization in different namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, customization, name-lookup, customization-point

I recently learned about customization point object pattern and tried implementing it. At first, it looked like a very good way to make some base functionality and extend it on different types.

In examples below I use Visual Studio 2022 with c++20 enabled.

I ended up with this code, similar to this. I used std::ranges::swap as a reference.

```cpp
namespace feature {
    namespace _feature_impl {
        /* to eliminate lookup for wrong functions */
        template<typename T>
        void use_feature(T&) = delete;

        /* filtering customizations */
        template<typename T>
        concept customization =
            requires(T& reward) {
                { use_feature(reward) };
            };

        struct fn {
            /* allow only if there is customization */
            /* compile-time error otherwise */
            constexpr void operator () (customization auto& reward) const {
                use_feature(reward);
            }
        };
    }

    /* main interface to access feature */
    inline constexpr auto apply = _feature_impl::fn{};
}
```

Examples of usage when it **works as expected**.

- Struct and customization function defined in global namespace

```cpp
/* result: compiles, prints "Foo" */
struct Foo {};

void use_feature(Foo&) {
    std::cout << "Foo\n";
}

auto main(int argc, char const** argv) -> int {
    auto foo = Foo{};
    feature::apply(foo);
    
    return 0;
}
```

- Same as before, but customization is not defined

```cpp
/* result: doesn't compile */
struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

void use_feature(Foo&) {
    std::cout << "Foo\n";
}

auto main(int argc, char const** argv) -> int {
    auto bar = Bar{};
    /* passing an object of type, that is not supported */
    feature::apply(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

- Same as the first example, but struct, customization function and usage of the feature are inside of namespace bar

```cpp
/* result: compiles, prints "Foo" */
namespace bar {
    struct Foo {};

    void use_feature(Foo&) {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }

    void main() {
        auto foo = Foo{};
        feature::apply(foo);
    }
}

auto main(int argc, char const** argv) -> int {
    bar::main();

    return 0;
}
```

- Putting `bar::main` in `bar::baz::main`

```cpp
/* result: compiles, prints "Foo" */
namespace bar {
    struct Foo {};

    void use_feature(Foo&) {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }

    namespace baz {
        /* now usage in nested namespace baz */
        void main() {
            auto foo = Foo{};
            feature::apply(foo);
        }
    }
}

auto main(int argc, char const** argv) -> int {
    bar::baz::main();

    return 0;
}
```

But there are some examples that a can't quite understand, why they **don't work**.

- Struct and customization defined in different namespace. Customization function can clearly see the definition, but when accessing though feature interface function `feature::apply`, I'm getting error.

```cpp
/* result: doesn't compiles */
/* Error C3889 - call to object of class type 'feature::_feature_impl::fn': no matching call operator found */
struct Foo {};
namespace bar {
    void use_feature(Foo&) {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }

    void main() {
        auto foo = Foo{};
        feature::apply(foo);
    }
}

auto main(int argc, char const** argv) -> int {
    bar::main();

    return 0;
}
```

- Defining customization function for built-in types like int.

```cpp
/* result: doesn't compiles */
/* Error C3889 - call to object of class type 'feature::_feature_impl::fn': no matching call operator found */
void use_feature(int&) {
    std::cout << "Foo\n";
}

auto main(int argc, char const** argv) -> int {
    auto i = int{0};
    feature::apply(i);

    return 0;
}
```

May be I'm missing some scope resolution rules with the first not working example, but even that doesn't explain why it doesn't work with built-in types with any combinations of namespaces.
std::ranges::swap does the same things. It means if, for example, I need to add customization for some type, I need to place it in the same namespace where this class is defined.

Assuming, that in standard library there is no `swap(std::string&, std::string&)` or I, for some reason, need to replace it, I should do something like this.

```cpp
namespace std {
    void swap(std::string&, std::string&) {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }
}

auto main(int argc, char const** argv) -> int {
    auto s = std::string{};
    std::ranges::swap(s, s);

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't feel right to me.

Initially I thought that lookup for function `use_feature` will be delayed until `feature::apply` call, because `feature::apply::operator()` was a function template, and call to `use_feature` inside this function used templated argument. It looked like an easy and flexible way to extent functionality on different types. But than I implemented it, tried to move around parts in different namespaces and tried to use with different types...

It seemed logical to me that customization functions `use_feature` would be looked up in current namespace or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first non compiling example fails, because `use_feature()` is meant to found by [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). That however requires the function to be declared in the same namespace as its argument. Your `use_feature(Foo&)` is declared in a *nested* namespace `bar` and is thus not considered by ADL.

The second example fails because ADL does not apply to fundamental types so the function that is found by overload resolution in `fn::operator()` is the deleted `use_feature` function template.

You can solve this by declaring `use_feature(int&)` in namespace `_feature_impl`

> Initially I thought that lookup for function use_feature will be delayed until feature::apply call, because feature::apply::operator() was a function template, and call to use_feature inside this function used templated argument.

This is correct, the last two examples fail because the deleted `use_feature` function template is still the best candidate found during overload resolution.

Also carefully read the rules of ADL on cppreference. They are quite complex but they do answer your question.

> Assuming, that in standard library there is no swap(std::string&, std::string&) or I, for some reason, need to replace it, I should do something like this.

**No.** Even if this is not what you are asking for, this is a misconception. It is undefined behaviour to add members to namespace `std` or to overload functions in it, unless otherwise specified. In short you may only specialize class templates that depend on at least one user defined type. From C++20 on it is always UB to specialize function templates.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the lead. I will look into ADL rules.

I'm not sure how I feel about restriction that argument and function should be in the same namespace. I guess this is what was bothering me the most. I'm sure there was a reason to do this, but it feel counter intuitive if take into account example first not working example, when function by itself works, but though ADL don't.

Comment: I know about std. Example with `std::range::swap` was meant to illustrate 2 points.
1. std::range::swap is acting the same
2. in order to add standard type (std::string) using this customization point, the function should be in the same namespace as std::string.

Comment: Based on what You said, I just need add a different method or workaround to add customizations for fundamental types and types from standard library.

Comment: To add customizations for fundamental types and types from `std`, you need to declare them in namespace `feature::_feature_impl`. This should however not be an issue since you control the API. These customization points are usually meant for users of your library to add special behaviour for _their_ types.